# Static void sort method doesn't sort passed collection in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm calling a method like this:

```
    final List<TimeCard> timeCards = new ArrayList<TimeCard>();
    ListFactory.populateLists(accounts, consultants, timeCards);
    ...
    TimeCardListUtil.sortByStartDate(timeCards);
    System.out.println("Time cards by date:");
    for (TimeCard tc : timeCards) {
        System.out.printf("  %s, %s%n", tc.getWeekStartingDay(), tc.getConsultant());
        }
```

And here is the method declaration:

```
    public static void sortByStartDate(List<TimeCard> timeCards){
        timeCards.stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getWeekStartingDay().compareTo(e2.getWeekStartingDay())).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
    }
```

The println in the method declaration prints the correct order, but if I print the list from the calling class, the order is unchanged.

Please help. I haven't been able to find solutions because I possibly don't know how to phrase the question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have sorted the stream**, NOT THE `List<TimeCard>` which is passed in.

Assign back the `timeCards` variable within the `sortByStartDate` method. You will get the change reflected outside the method.

*use `collet()` in order to do this.*

```
public static void sortByStartDate(List<TimeCard> timeCards){
 timeCards = timeCards.stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getWeekStartingDay().compareTo(e2.getWeekStartingDay())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Alternative clean way is:

```
timeCards.sort((e1, e2) -> e1.getWeekStartingDay().compareTo(e2.getWeekStartingDay()));
```

**Update:**

You can simplify the sorting by without passing the lambda, but get the advantage of method references with the `Comparator` class.

```
public static void sortByStartDate(List<TimeCard> timeCards){
     timeCards = timeCards.stream()
                .sort(Comparator.comparing(TimeCard::getWeekStartingDay)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: I tried this exactly, but it didn't work. What could I be missing?

Comment: @Ian Is the list you pass in the actual list, or a copy?

Comment: It is the actual list. I've added a couple additional lines above.

Comment: @Jude The clean way worked. Any idea why the other didn't?

Comment: Instead of `(e1, e2) -> e1.getWeekStartingDay().compareTo(e2.getWeekStartingDay())`, you can use `Comparator.comparing(TimeCard::getWeekStartingDay)`

Answer (score 2):

The sorted() function doesn't change the stream that it operates on. You need to make your function return the result of the sorted() function.

Comment: What if the method is void and doesn't return a value?

Comment: @IanHalloran if you want to use the sorted() function to sort, you need to either rewrite the list with its result, or change your function to not be void and use its return value.